# Flex 4 List - scrollbars become visible and cover the itemrenderer

Tags: apache-flex, listview, scrollbar, itemrenderer

I have a list inside a VDividedBox.  When the box is resized so the vertical scrollbar shows on the list, it covers some of the itemrenderers.  How do I get the list to resize horizontally so that the scrollbar does not cover the renderers?

Comment: Can you post your code? Is there a container around your list?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm fairly sure it's not the list scrollbar that's showing, but the VDividedBox's, hence why it's covering the list.  It's a known bug in Flex 3.  If I were you, I'd set the height of the list at 100% and remove the scrollbar by doing `horizontalScollPolicy="off"` on the VDividedBox.